# How does Google determine which search engine to redirect to when using Sitelinks Searchbox rich snippets?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets, google-sitelinks-searchbox

We are specifying internal search in our structured data:

[image: JSON-LD structured data using the "WebSite" and "SearchAction" types]

But, when people search in the sitelinks searchbox, they get redirected to:

```
Search term site:ourbrand.com
```

I am actually happy with this but would like to know how it works and is this normal behaviour? In order for this to continue, can we specify Google's search in our declaration?

Answer (score 2):

In you descriptions it sounds like users are taken to a google search result page for [Search term site:ourbrand.com](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=Search%20term%20site%3Aourbrand.com&oq=Search%20term%20site%3Aourbrand.com&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.999j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

If that is the case, no this in not normal behaviour if you have implemented the sitelinks search box schema, as you have done.  This is the default behaviour if you haven't implemented the schema.

If the schema is working correctly, the user should be redirected from Google search pages to the search result page on *your* site.

Looking at your mark up, that should be

```
https://www.yoursite.xx.xx/customercentre/search?query=Search+term
```

Looking at your schema mark up example, it all looks correct.  Perhaps the search result URL from your site is incorrect? Also if you haven't already, double check the mark up in Google validator:

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/